# Facebook permission warning user_friends but already finished verification

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I already got the permission for `user_friends`. Business verification and other contracts are also signed and approved. But yesterday, I just got an alert message [like in this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8zt8.png)

Aside from Business Verification and Supplemental Terms, are there other steps I have to complete?

Thank you

Comment: the error message tells you exactly what to do, i am not sure what to add, to be honest. just do it.

Comment: @luschn Business verification is already verified and other contracts are already signed and approved.